# Check if tab is active

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my problem.

I have 2 Tabs. **First tab I have a button and in the second tab I have a select**.

When I click the button with the `id="select-"` I want to trigger the change on `$('#selector')`. My problem is that the selector still doesn't exist (when I click the tab-content is not loaded yet.

So instead of click I wanted something like when tab-content loads or when tab is active. Any help?

```
//when select is clicked update parameters on load
$('[id^="select-"]').click(function () {
    $('#selector').trigger('change');
});
```

Edit: no it's not duplicate...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: @sdada It isn't duplicate. Why do you use such language?

Comment: Because I'm tired of people locking my posts with duplicates that have nothing to do with my problem.

Comment: "When the tab-content loads or when tab is active" - how are you creating your tabs?  There should be an event when they are made active at least, if they're you're own tabs, then just raise an event.

Comment: @fen1x It *might* be a duplicate, just not a duplicate of the suggested event binding on dynamically created elements.

Comment: That tab content is there but it's not displayed until I click on the button. So i'm guessing until the selector is loaded the id doesn't exist and I get undefined...

Comment: Then you'll have to "queue" up the calls.  On the click, check if the element exists, if not add it to a queue of things to do when it does exist.  When you create the element, check the queue and action everything.  If it's just a simple case of 'active this' then no need for a queue as a simple flag will suffice.  They key being you check this when you do finally load the element that it will effect.